# Convert a pandas series of lists with variable length into a 1d array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas series of lists. Now i need one big list with all lists concatenated. With `df.msg.values` I get get something like this:

```
array([list(['hi']), list(['hi', 'cat', 'dog']),  list(['smoke', 'red']),...)
```

The output should now be an numpy array like this:

```
['hi', 'hi', 'cat', 'dog', 'smoke', 'red',...]
```

My working solution is a for loop which concatenates all lists.

```
tok = tokenized.msg.dropna()
1darr= np.array([])
for m in tok :
    1darr = np.concatenate([1darr, m])
```

Since `np.concatenate()` can get slow for millions of rows I tried `np.ravel()` or `np.flatten()` but nothing will work. It will not flatten it into an 1d array. Does somebody know how I could get my desired solution efficiently?

Comment: The best solution here might be to avoid your problem entirely - take a step backwards, and figure out how to avoid having a Series of Python lists. That in and of itself is inefficient.

Comment: We are working with DataFrames and now I can't just change my whole system. Thats why I tried to get the the numpy array of a series via `values` and then do my operations. At the end I just need the vocabulary of the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me working:

```
a = np.concatenate(df['msg']).tolist()
print (a)
['hi', 'hi', 'cat', 'dog', 'smoke', 'red']
```

Or:

```
from  itertools import chain  

a = list(chain.from_iterable(df['msg']))
print (a)
['hi', 'hi', 'cat', 'dog', 'smoke', 'red']:
```

Or:

```
a = [y for x in df['msg'] for y in x]
```

Comment: Thanks, I did some tests and itertools was always slightly faster then the third solution. Will use itertools for now.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply run `np.array(df['msg'].sum())`.